# How to reference a JavaScript library in Haxe

Tags: javascript, haxe

I was reading about fluid dynamics and came across [this](https://github.com/haxiomic/GPU-Fluid-Experiments/tree/snow) awesome project. After building it, I noticed that the little option menu that appears in the [demo](http://haxiomic.github.io/GPU-Fluid-Experiments/html5/) is not showing.

So, as I am completely new to Haxe, I thought that adding the little GUI options panel would be a great little challenge in an attempt to familiarise myself with Haxe. However, I have fallen at the first hurdle as I am getting the following error whilst trying to build the GUI that sits on top of the fluid experiment as shown in the demo:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: dat is not defined

Inside the projects route directory, I have an `src` folder, then `Main.hx`; inside `Main.hx` at the bottom of the `init()` function, I am doing the following:

```
import dat.GUI;

function init():Void {
    //other unrelated code goes here

    var gui = new dat.GUI({autoPlace: true});
    //particle count
    var particleCountGUI = gui.add(particles, 'count').name('Particle Count').listen();
}
```

When I run the program, the console prints the error mentioned.

**Things I have done:**

Inside `project.flow` in the route directory, I have made reference to dat in the build dependencies (and downloaded [dat.gui](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui) of course).

I have even tried using other frameworks to build the GUI, but I keep getting errors in the console log even if the build is successful. I did have luck getting a panel added, but rather than sitting on top of the fluid experiment, it pushed the whole thing down so there was a space between the panel and the fluid experiment.

Ideally, I want to recreate the options panel shown in the demo, but make it a scrollable list instead. However, I need to understand why I am having issues with `dat` first!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to add this to `init()` (assuming the `.js` is located in the project root):

```
haxe.macro.Compiler.includeFile("dat.gui.min.js");
```

[`includeFile()`](https://api.haxe.org/haxe/macro/Compiler.html#includeFile) is a [macro](https://haxe.org/manual/macro.html) that directly embeds the file into the `.js` generated by Haxe (by default at the top of the file). That's enough to make the UI show up for me:

[image]

The alternative would be to add a `<script>` tag to the `index.html` file as documented [here](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui#packaged-builds). I'm not familiar enough with the flow build tool to know that's done in this case, but you'd have to find a way to:

- modify the `index.html` template to include the `<script>` tag
- make it copy the `min.js` to the `bin/web` directory.

So yeah, `includeFile()` definitely seems like the more convenient option. :)